# UV divergence in QFT and trouble with 4-dimensional volume integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform

This might seem like a very stupid question but I'm currently struggling to see how this type of integral diverges at high energies when considering $d^4p$ as Fourier transform of $d^4x$

$$ \int{d^4p} \frac{1}{(p^2-\Delta+i\epsilon)^2} $$

If I just think about it as $d^np = p^{n-1} dp d\Omega$, then it's easy. We have at high energies something on the lines of $\sim p^3/p^4$ and this obviously diverges as we integrate it.

What causes me trouble is in fact if we think of $d^4k$ as the Fourier transform of $d^4x$. For $d^4x = dtd\vec{x}$, can we see $d^4p$ as $dEd\vec{p}=dE\;p^2dpd\Omega$ and integral is

$$ \int{dEdpd\Omega} \frac{p^2}{(p^2-\Delta+i\epsilon)^2} $$

At high energies, this is $\sim p^2/p^4$ and divergence disappears. So there's clearly something wrong in here.

Comment: How are you planning to do the integral over $E$?

Comment: That's a good point...